# Git subtree pull overwriting another subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a repository with quite a few (5-50) subtrees merged into it. When I initially pulled down all the subtrees, everything went as expected. Every once in a while, I switch to my `upstream-subtrees` branch to pull all changes into. This generally works.

But, twice now, I've had that pull replace the contents of directory `A` (pointing to remote repository `A`) with the contents of repository `B` (a different subtree in directory `B` pointing to a different repsitory). I have no idea why this would be happening. When I run `git remote -v` to see if my remotes got messed up or something, everything looks good.

Also, it's not like directory `A` always gets overwritten with repository `B`. Sometimes `D` gets overwritten with `C`, for example.

I don't even know where to begin looking to debug this. Any ideas?

Comment: how exactly do you run the pulls?

Comment: I am attempting to follow https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge ; specifically for the pulls I do `git pull -s subtree A master`, then `git pull -s subtree B master`, ...

Comment: You should have a look at `git subtree` (a different tool) and `gitmodules`. I think they are better suited for your situation.

Comment: I changed my pull command to `git pull -s recursive -X subtree=A/ A master` after seeing that example on here for similar question. I'll take a look at `git subtree`.